# How to compare char between 128 to 256 in ASCII in c++?

Tags: c++

I create a function in c++ to filter some characters, however it's don't work with character between 128 to 256 in ASCII.

```cpp
string parseString(string str) {
    string result = "";
    string temp = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') || (str[i] >= 'á' && str[i] <= 'û') || (str[i] >= 160 && str[i] <= 165) || (str[i] >= 198 && str[i] <= 199) || str[i] == 39) {
            result += tolower(str[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Some examples:

```cpp
parseString('word@#$%¨$%#$@#%$'); //return word
// however
parseString('Fréderic'); //return Frederic, however the function don't filter 130 character
```

How can I use AscII 256 in c++?

Comment: Start with [How do I properly use std::string on UTF-8 in C++? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403342/how-do-i-properly-use-stdstring-on-utf-8-in-c).

Comment: `'word@#$%¨$%#$@#%$'` and `'Fréderic'` are not a string literals.

Comment: `'word@#$%¨$%#$@#%$'` is not a string, it's a "char" or actually `int`. And modern code typically uses UTF-8 so you have to handle Unicode properly

Comment: Or [c++ - set encoding of string literals to latin1 with gcc - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107831/set-encoding-of-string-literals-to-latin1-with-gcc) / [How to convert a String from UTF8 to Latin1 in C/C++? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855643/how-to-convert-a-string-from-utf8-to-latin1-in-c-c).

Comment: *it doesn't work with character between 128 to 256 in ASCII*  Nor should it, since ASCII is a 7-bit encoding going from 0 to 127.  So anything in the 128 to 256 range isn't ASCII.

Comment: Also `char` doesn't have any characters between 128 and 256, not everywhere. `char` can be signed or unsigned.

Comment: @user202729 please please don't use Latin1. For example printing Latin1 encoded strings to your utf-8 terminal might print the incorrect characters. Let us embrace the Unicode standard as the one standard to rule all them all (the languages).

Answer (score 2):

The type `char` is used as the elements of `std::string`. Whether `char` is signed depends on the environment. You should cast the value to `unsigned char` before comparision.

```cpp
string parseString(string str) {
    string result = "";
    string temp = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        unsigned char c = static_cast<unsigned char>(str[i]);
        if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'á' && c <= 'û') || (c >= 160 && c <= 165) || (c >= 198 && c <= 199) || c == 39) {
            result += tolower(c);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then, single quotations `''` is for character constants in C++. You should use double quotations `""` to express strings.

```cpp
parseString("word@#$%¨$%#$@#%$");
parseString("Fréderic");
```

Even after this change, your code (especially the part `(c >= 'á' && c <= 'û')` may not work if you are using character set that uses multiple bytes to express `á` and `û` (for example, UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

The problem of comparing non-ascii characters is challenging. You have to account for the following issues:

1. There are different encodings (ASCII is not one of them) that can encode the character `'é'`. Possible are [for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89#Character_mappings):

   - in ISO/IEC 8859 as 1 byte `0xe9`
   - in Unicode UTF-16 as 2 bytes `0x00 0xe9`
   - in Unicode UTF-8 as 2 bytes `0xc3 0xa9`
2. In Unicode, which is most likely what you are using, there are even more than one possible code point sequences for `é`:

   - From the [Latin-1 Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement) block:
     **U+0039** (`0x00 0xe9` in UTF-16 or `0xc3 0xa9` in UTF-8)
   - A normal `e` combined with a [diacritical mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks):
     **U+0065 U+0301** (`0x00 0x65 0x03 0x01` in UTF-16 or `0x65 0xcc 0x81` in UTF-8)

The first problem is easy to take care of. You need to find out what character encoding your text editor is using to write the `é` to the source file. And you have to adjust your algorithm to work with multibyte characters. For [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding) for example each multibyte character starts with a binary `0b11...` byte and ends with an `0b10...` byte. The single character bytes are `0b0...`.

The second problem is only a problem if you work with user input. Unicode defines a procedure known as [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization), that transforms equivalent code point sequences (like the both ways to represent 'é' above) into a canonical form, that can be used for comparison.

If you now think (like I would), that this is way to much complicated stuff, I would recommend using a string library that is able to deal with those kind of things properly. A starting could be the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884854/unicode-string-normalization-in-c-c) question.

Answer (score -1):

There is no é in ASCII. ASCII stops at 127.

But in Unicode é is 233. That might explain why your filter fails. But to really understand what is happening you need to know what encoding your compiler is using.

Try this code

```
cout << (int)'é' << '\n';
```

and see what number it prints.

Comment: doing this is a bad idea. In many encodings like UTF-8 `'é'` would be a multibyte character

Comment: @phuclv which should give a compiler error like e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1KvPse3oa)